# How to filter lists that contain both links and plain text?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, html-entities

I have a function that filters a list on input. It works for the `<a>` links and plain text (like `city` and `village`), but only separately:

```html
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <label for='listFilter'>Filter: </label>
  <input type='search' id='listSearch' />

  <ul id='list1'>
    <li><a href='#.html'>San Carlos</a>, city</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>La Paz</a>, village</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>Alicia</a>, city</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>Lopez</a>, city</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>San Isidro Sur</a>, village</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>Santa&#8209;Clara</a>, city</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>La&#160;Libertad</a>, village</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>Santo Ni&#241;o</a>, village</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I get the filter function to work when typing both the links and plain text? (Like when I type `san carlos city` or `san carlos, city`, it display only`<li><a href='#.html'>San Carlos</a>, city</li>` in the filter results?

**UPDATE**:
The problem with using `innerText` is the filter won't parse/recognize html entities which I need included in some of my lists:

```
<li><a href='#.html'>Santa&#8209;Clara</a>, city</li>
<li><a href='#.html'>La&#160;Libertad</a>, village</li>
<li><a href='#.html'>Santo Ni&#241;o</a>, village</li>
```

For example, typing `la libertad` does not display `La Libertad` because it uses the HTML entity `&#160;` (non-breaking space) instead of a "normal space". How can the function also recognize such HTML entities?

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerText` to avoid HTML tags.

```js
function filterList() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("listSearch");
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("list1");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    b = li[i];
    if (b.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

var listFilter = document.getElementById("listSearch");
if (listFilter) {
  listFilter.oninput = filterList;
}
```

```html
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <label for='listFilter'>Filter: </label>
  <input type='search' id='listSearch' />

  <ul id='list1'>
    <li><a href='#.html'>San Carlos</a>, city</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>La Paz</a>, village</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>Alicia</a>, city</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>Lopez</a>, city</li>
    <li><a href='#.html'>San Isidro Sur</a>, village</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

## Resources

- [`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)

  > Node.innerText is a property that represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I also need html entities like non-breaking hyphens, non-breaking space, and special characters in some of the list entries. Please check the updated demo.